# Sort multidimensional array of subarrays

Tags: php

I have this array $allStatusChanges with subarrays
I wont to display the data like name- in ascending order, and I done this, but the date?

```
"Uliana Hrebenik" => array:2 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Uliana Hrebenik"
      "date" => "2022-05-13"
      "Departament" => "North Europe"
      "Domain" => "United Kingdom"
      "status change" => "German Break"
    ]
    1 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Uliana Hrebenik"
      "date" => "2022-05-20"
      "Departament" => "North Europe"
      "Domain" => "United Kingdom"
      "status change" => "German Break"
    ]
  ]
  "Uros Djordjevic" => array:1 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Uros Djordjevic"
      "date" => "20-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "Bike24"
      "Domain" => "Customer Care"
    ]
  ]
  "Valentin Hanu" => array:1 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentin Hanu"
      "date" => "2022-05-05"
      "Departament" => "Accounting"
      "Domain" => "Invoices"
      "status change" => "German Break"
    ]
  ]
  "Valentina Herciu" => array:18 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "02-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "03-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    2 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "04-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    3 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "05-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    4 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "06-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    5 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "09-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
    6 => array:5 [
      "name" => "Valentina Herciu"
      "date" => "10-05-2022"
      "status change" => "Log Hours"
      "Departament" => "office management"
      "Domain" => ""
    ]
```

I sort the name of user in ascending order, and it is ok, but i wont to sort and the date for each user in descending order

> 

```
>         $date = [];
>         $name = [];
>        foreach ($allStatusChanges as $users=>$values){
>            foreach ($values as $value){
>                $name[$users] = $value['name'];
>                $date[$users][]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['date']));
>            
>            array_multisort( $name, SORT_ASC, $allStatusChanges);
>            }
>        }
```

The question is how can I sort for every user the date for each status change in descending order
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJm0r.png)

Comment: ı  wondered, about why you don't use usort function

Comment: use array multisort `array_multisort( array_column($yourArray, "name"), SORT_ASC, $yourArray );`

Comment: the problem is how to sort by date, after sorting by name

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476, "Sorting by multiple fields"

Comment: I solve in this vay:                                                                                                                                  $date=array_column($allStatusChange[$users], 'date');
 ksort($allStatusChange);
   array_multisort( $date, SORT_DESC, $allStatusChange[$users]);